# How to update nested array of objects in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of object like this:

```
const tempobj = [
{
    id: "1",
    fanimate: [
        {
            id: "111",
            animate: "xyz",
        },
    ],
},];
```

Now I want to add more animations inside this array, such that each object gets added in the fanimate such that:

```
const tempobj = [
{
    id: "1",
    fanimate: [
        {
            id: "111",
            animate: "xyz",
        },
        {
            id: "222",
            animate: "def",
        },
    ],
},];
```

I tried using the hook useState, but I am getting undefined results

Answer (score 0):

```
const tempobj = [
{
    id: "1",
    fanimate: [
        {
            id: "111",
            animate: "xyz",
        },
    ],
}];

const modified = tempobj.map(temp => {
  const newtemp = {
    id: temp.id,
    fanimate: [...temp.fanimate, {id:"222", animate:"def"}]
  }
  return newtemp;
})

console.log(modified);
```

Comment: How can I do this iteratively so that I can keep on adding?

Answer (score 0):

You could just spread all the places

```
const tempObj = {
id:'1',
fan:[
{
  id:'2',
  animate:'xyz'
}
]
}



console.log(tempObj)

 const newtest={...testObj,fan:[...testObj.fan, {id:'3', animate:'tuz'}]}

 console.log(newtest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const tempobj = [
  {
    id: "1",
    fanimate: [
      {
        id: "111",
        animate: "xyz"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const [state, setState] = useState(tempobj);

function updateArray(newItem) {
  setState(
    state.map((item) => ({ ...item, fanimate: [...item.fanimate, newItem] }))
  );
}
```

You can push the `newItem` to the original fanimate array using spread operator, everytime a new item is added, the original array data is copied by `...item.fanimate`:

```
{ ...item, fanimate: [...item.fanimate, newItem] }
```

BTW the naming of `tempobj` really should be `tempArr` or `tempArray`.

[A working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-waterfall-k0b1vj)